# Block in MRC why this code not crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

File Person.h

```
@interface Person:NSObject
+ (void)callBlock:(void (^)())block;
@end
```

File Person.m

```
@imp:
+ (void)callBlock:(void (^)())block
{ 
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
   block();
}
@end
```

Code in ViewDidLoad:

```
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
void (^block)() = ^{
NSLog(@"%@"，p);
  [p release];
}
[Person callBlock:block];
```

---

finish!

MyQuestion:

1. in main function, block var is a stackblock,and this block assign to the function +callBlock:,and the block in Person.m is also a stackblock. Content of them are same.
2. In my opinion,the block in main will be free by system before called in Person.m, so I think this program will crash, but it run normal. why?
3. And i think my code is same as below.

...

```
 void example_addBlockToArray(NSMutableArray *array) {
   char b = 'B';
   [array addObject:^{
      printf("%cn", b);
   }];
 }

 void example() {
      NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
      example_addBlockToArray(array);
      void (^block)() = [array objectAtIndex:0];
      block();
    }
```

This programe crashed！ which the difference between them?

Sorry! both program use mrc!!! i did not  write clearly!

Comment: Why do you think the block will be freed at all?

Comment: if this code is in a viewcontroller, in viewdidload,will this crash? i try this!

Comment: a stackblock not free after function?

Comment: Yes, but the function does not go out-of-scope until after the block is called.

Comment: What @trojanfoe is trying to say is that all the calls are synchronous, so the function is in scope until after the block() returns.

Comment: oh! i understand!  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, you're using manual memory management.

Therefore is an explanation:

**Person object case**

1. You create the object
2. You create the block
3. You call the block
4. Block logs the object out
5. Block frees the object
   That's why there is no crash

**Char log case**

Since you're not using ARC, it goes this way:

1. You add the block that logs char
2. Once you leave the function that adds the block to an array, the char you've just created **is going to be released from memory**.
   In case if you use ARC for memory management, it will keep this char alive in the memory, until this block exists. But once you remove it from an array and block's reference count equals to 0, this char also being released.
3. You take a block from an array
4. Call it, it references to a memory address of char that already released, crash appears. As explained in your error:
   ***EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)***
   Means, that you point to zero address (null pointer exception in other words).

So, that's it.

Comment: Why do you think ARC is not being used?

Comment: @Avi "Why do you think ARC is not being used?" because of `[p release];`  ;)

Comment: I think the ARC is not used, since in the author's example uses release message on object. And it really crashes without ARC, and works good with ARC. You can try it yourself.

Comment: The second example does not have any MMM, and it crashes under ARC, as expected.  ARC vs MMM has nothing to do with the explanation.

Comment: @Avi Honestly, Alex is pretty close to what actually happens: when the block will be released, it releases also all imported variables which have been copied to the heap.

Comment: As for poor grasp.. C manually frees primitives once you leave the block where it's created. In case of using ARC it seems it keeps it in memory since there is a reference in NSLog function. I'm not the best theoretician, but it might be an explanation.

Comment: The whole point of capturing values in a closure is that the original reference can go out of scope, but the value is still available to the block.  The variable going out of scope is not the problem.  The problem is that an uncopied stack block is added to an array, and then the stack block('s closure data) is wiped out when the function returns.  It just so happens that if you get unlucky, the stack isn't modified before the block is called, and it works.

Comment: @Avi You are close as well, but I'm pretty sure, the `char` will be _copied_ into the closure's imported variables. If the block will not be copied, though, the compiler may apply optimisations - that is, not allocating bytes for storing the copy of the char. However, when the block will be copied (in case of ARC) then there will be an area on the heap where `b` has been copied and where the code references the imported variable.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, you may be right that if the compiler can be sure that the variable is not changed, it need not actually create a copy.  However, that is purely implementation, and it doesn't explain the logical bug that is actually causing the crash.  The bug is that stack data is being referenced after the stack frame went out of scope.  It doesn't matter whether the closure data was actually the same spot on the stack as the variable `b` or not.

Comment: I see that ARC does cause a copy of the block to be made implicitly when it's added to the array.  So the answer is both the lack of ARC and the stack block leaving scope.

Comment: @Avi You are right for MMM. In ARC, though the block will be copied. We can confirm this with disassembling the sample code. The code calls `objc_retainBlock` which creates a copy of the block on the heap. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id71

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the first example does not crash because the block is defined in a function scope which doesn't end until after the block is called.

The second example, on the other hand, defines the block in a secondary function, which ends before the block is called.  Thus, at the time of the block invocation, the stack has already been modified and the block has become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

After main function executed  the block in main will be free by system ，not before called in Person.m. I tried the second code in viewcontroller, it works fine, not crash.

Comment: The second set of code will crash, unless one is (un)lucky.

Comment: I run this code in viewcontroller. It print "Bn".                                        `@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    example();
}

void example_addBlockToArray(NSMutableArray *array) {
    char b = 'B';
    [array addObject:^{
        printf("%cn", b);
    }];
}

void example() {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    example_addBlockToArray(array);
    void (^block)() = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    block();
}

@end
`

Comment: And, therefore?  As I said, if you're unlucky, it won't crash.  There's no guarantee that the stack will be modified before the block is invoked, but it's a horrible bug to assume it won't be.  Hence why it's **un**lucky when it doesn't crash for you.

Comment: OK，I am newcomer to iOS，not quite understand your question

Comment: I think the problem is scope of variable

Comment: Never mind me, under ARC it's not an issue because blocks are implicitly copied as needed.